# show executed query in phpPgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

Is there a way to show the SQL query executed by phpPgAdmin as the way phpMyAdmin does?
For example, if I modify a column, it should show the `ALTER` command being executed.

If this is not possible, what other interface could I use to get this feature?

Comment: This would be really nice, im looking for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with any currently released version of phpPgAdmin, although the feature could probably be added. You'd need to intercept the SQL being sent to the back-end, and then display this back out to the user. SQL execution is pretty well centralized, and if you look at the "history" feature you will see a way to trap/show queries, so munging those bits together would probably get you what you want. HTH, if someone implements this, please send a pull request!

Comment: Please, need this feature! I came from phpMyAdmin, this phpPgAdmin is very hard to use.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick dirty hack you could alter sources a bit to enable sql logging:
In classes/database/ADODB_base.php in

```
function execute($sql) {
...
}
```

add these lines at the beginning:

```
global $misc;
$misc->saveScriptHistory($sql);
```

This worked in my 5.0.3 version.